# Filter content by url segments

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have a database of both movies and tv shows. I want to filter these like so:
/productions/ = index (all), /productions/films/ = only films, and /productions/series/ = only tv shows

```
## urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from productions import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^films/$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='films'),
    url(r'^series/$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='series'),
)

## views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

from productions.models import Production, Director

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'productions/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'productions_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Production.objects.order_by('-release')
```

What would be the best practice for something like this? Create a new method in views.py for each, or could I reuse the main method, and call something like if(productions.is_movie) by somehow parsing the URL segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd capture the string from url, like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?<query>(films|series|))/$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='films_series'),
)
```

Then, in `get_queryset()` method I'd check whether you need to return all, films or series:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'productions/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'productions_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # analyze `self.kwargs` and decide should you filter or not, just for example:
        is_all = self.kwargs['query'] == ''
        is_movie = self.kwargs['query'] == 'films' 
        is_series = self.kwargs['query'] == 'series'

        return Production.objects.order_by('-release')  # TODO: filter movies or series
```